Static route nested within dynamic route behaving as dynamic
I'm new to learning Next.js, and based on my understanding, routes are static by default unless they're calling a dynamic method such as noStore() or cookies().
Say you have a scenario, where you have a dynamic route, say /dashboard Nested within the route is /dashboard/users, which is not calling any dynamic methods and thus should be static.
Upon testing, /dashboard is fetched from the server upon request time as expected, however /dashboard/users is also fetched upon request, but I'd expect it to be static?
